# Displaying Select Box from enum data

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Here is my enum model:

```
enum (Station) {
  description (List of station in Bart Schedule)
  symbol (12th St. Oakland City Center)
  symbol (16th St. Mission)
}
```

I am trying to display the above enum model in select box value but its not reflecting.

```
input-view{
  match: Station(Station)

  message(Where would you like to board from?)

  render{
    // auto-complete
    selection-of (Station){
      where-each (Station) {
        single-line{
          text{
            value{
              template ("#{value(Station)}")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: The input-view looks good. Can you add your Action code to the description?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

Define a default-init in action and supply it with selection value. The render block won't automatically display all possible enum values. Download this [sample capsule](https://github.com/MinChengVivLabs/example.enum) at Github.

```
action (ActionDisplayGrade) {
  description (__DESCRIPTION__)
  type (Search)
  collect {
    input (grade) {
      type (EnumGrade)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal: ActionGetAllEnumGrade
        }
      }
    }
  }
  output (TypeTxt)
}
```

Please also note, your input-view code might work, but the style is NOT recommended. There are Three definitions of **Station** in your code, and each replace previous definition. It's better to code it this way:

```
input-view{
  match: Station(this)

  message(Where would you like to board from?)

  render{
    // auto-complete
    selection-of (this){
      where-each (item) {
        single-line{
          text{
            value{
              template ("#{value(item)}")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```